# MonacaのBasicプランで、Monacaデバッガーを複数人で使用

Tags: monaca

Monacaにてアプリ開発を行っております。
自社向けのスマホアプリですが、最初ということもありBasicプランで一人で開発を行っています。

システムを作成途中なのですが、社内の上役一人に報告ついでに実機でのデモを行いたいと思っております。

しかし、
（１）上役がiPhoneしか持っていない。
（２）離れた場所にいる（自分の端末を直接見せられない）。
という状況です。

iOSのadhocビルドも考えたのですが、ディベロッパープログラムが有料ということもあり、却下になりました。

そこで、MonacaデバッガーをiPhoneにインストールしてもらい、デバッグ画面を見てもらおうと思っております。

まず、上役にMonacaデバッガーをiPhoneにインストールしてもらい、自分のＩＤとパスワードを上司に伝えてログインしてもらうと思っております。

この方法しかないでしょうか？

MonacaのBasicプラン料金表をみてみると、「2台までの実機デバッグ」「テスターとしてプロジェクト参加」という記載があります。

私が開発者で、上役をテスターとしてプロジェクトに参加させたい場合は、何かスマートでいい方法があるのでしょうか？

技術的な質問ではないのですが、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 上役の方が所有のiPhoneにMonacaデバッガーをインストールすると、JuJun Juさんが残り1台分しか使えないことを懸念されているのですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。一台分しか使えないことは問題ないのですが、アカウントの使いまわしが気になっておりました。「テスターとしてプロジェクト参加」という記載があったので、スマートなやり方がほかにあるのかな？と思った次第です。

Answer (score 1):

ひとつのアカウントを使いまわすのには反対です。
アカウントの管理が杜撰になり、"何処で"、"誰が"ログインしているのか分からなくなるうえ
IDEのコンソール画面をアクセスされることで汚されます。

もし上記のような条件であれば
無料のアカウントをもう一つ作成し、
開発用アカウントにて
"ファイル"＞"エクスポート"を行いZIPを作成した後
デバッグ用アカウントで
"プロジェクト作成"＞"インポート"を行えばいいかと思います。

なお、"テスターとして参加"とは
"Goldプラン"以上のアカウントの開発者が最低一人必要です。
プロジェクト共有機能の受け口になれる……ということです

Comment: 「テスターとして参加」について、受け口という点が不明でしたので、よくわかりました。ありがとうございます。もう一つアカウントを作成という方法は考えていなかったので助かりました。

Comment: ちなみに受け口になれるだけで編集は出来ません。本当にテスターの扱いでデバッガからアクセスできるレベルですね。
開発者が複数人で共有する場合は、開発者人数分Goldプラン以上のアカウントが必要になります。